# springboot aws textract project occuring Web server failed to start. Port 9090 was already in use even after following steps to resolve

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, intellij-plugin, amazon-textract

I want build restapi or call web restapi by spring boot in which i am using aws textract where while running the apllication class Web server failed to start. Port 9090 was already in use. error is occuring

i tried to configure the error by killing process and rerunning it and changing the port number and also i build another project using spring boot where while running the application class server is started in port number means while e=when i build spring boot project for test it does't gave any such error. How to resolve it.As far as i think it is my prijecr spring boot aws textract that has some issue?